# Formating output from bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, formatting, wmic

```
wmic product get name,version > "C:\myInformation.txt"
ECHO.  >> "C:\myInformation.txt"
ECHO %username% >> "C:\myInformation.txt"
```

I'm trying to write a batch file that will generate the software installed on the users computer as well as get their username for id purposes. 
The code above works individually. However, when I try to write out to the file, I get `†਍敨瑣牯洮牡楴敮⁺਍` instead of "`john.doe`"

My question is, how can I get the software dump from `wmic` followed by the username without it spitting out garbage. 
I've flipped the order of commands. Doing so results in getting the username but not the software, in a neat output any ways.

Creating two files is not really something I want to do. I'd like one file per user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `/APPEND:"myfile.txt"` to output wmic in a file.
i.e.

```
echo. >"c:\myinformation.txt"
wmic /APPEND:"c:\myinformation.txt" product get name,version >nul
echo.  >> "c:\myinformation.txt"
echo %username% >> "c:\myinformation.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! Appreciate the help